# Representing $\mathbf{Tr}(A + BC^{-1}B^T)< K$ as an LMI

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, convex-optimization, control-theory

I am trying to implement a convex optimization and I have the constraint $\mathbf{Tr}(A + BC^{-1}B^T)< K$ where $A\succeq0,B,C\succ0$ are the decision variables. Can it be transformed into a linear constraint or a linear matrix inequality?

Comment: Are there any other constraints on the variables, e.g. positive-semidefinite?

Comment: As $A + B C^{-1} B^T$ is the Schur complement of the block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & - C \end{pmatrix}$. Although I don't see immediately how to relate the block matrix to the trace inequality without strengthening it to an operator inequality.

Comment: Hello @Rammus. Yes, I can assume $A \succeq0$ and $C\succ0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace can also be written as

$$
\mathbf{Tr}(A + B\,C^{-1}B^\top) = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i^\top (A + B\,C^{-1}B^\top)\,e_i, \tag{1}
$$

with $n$ such that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $e_i$ the $i$th column of an $n \times n$ identity matrix. By introducing intermediate scalar variables $\alpha_i$ one can write the initial inequality in an indirect way by using

\begin{align}
e_i^\top (A + B\,C^{-1}B^\top)\,e_i &< \alpha_i, \forall\,i = 1 \dots n, \tag{2} \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i &< K. \tag{3}
\end{align}

The inequality from $(3)$ is already a linear inequality. The inequality from $(2)$ can be formulated as linear (matrix) inequality by using the Schur complement. It can be noted that applying the Schur complement to each inequality from $(2)$ does require the additional assumptions that $C$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks Kwin. I can assume $A\succeq0$ and $C\succ0$ so your answer is perfect. I wanted to ask whether your reply is the easiest way to implement in CVX or that there is another form. Thanks again.

Comment: @Morad What is CVX?